# Can't vertically-align in a div

Tags: html, css, vertical-alignment

So I have a little problem with vertically aligning text inside a div. Even when I thought it might work (like in the big box in the example below), the text goes too much down.

In order to view the example, please view it in full screen.

```css
body
{
 font-family:Arial;
 font-size:10pt;
 color:white;
 background-color:#000856;
}
.clear
{
 clear:both;
}
#container
{
 padding-right:50px;
}
#container #siteHeader
{
 margin-top:40px;
}
#container #siteHeader .logo
{
 float:right;
}
#container #siteHeader .logoText
{
 float:right;
 font-weight:bold;
 font-size:25pt;
 padding-top:35px;
 padding-right:15px;
}
#container #siteBody
{
 
}
#container #siteBody .row
{
 margin-top:15px;
}
#container #siteBody .row .spacer
{
 width:20px;
 float:right;
}
#container #siteBody .row .block
{
 height:160px;
 text-align:center;
 font-size:25pt;
 font-weight:bold;
 float:right;
}
#container #siteBody .row .block span
{
 position:relative;
 top:50%;
 transform:translateY(-50%);
}
#container #siteBody .row .single
{
 width:160px;
}
#container #siteBody .row .double
{
 width:335px;
}
#container #siteBody .row .triple
{
 width:510px;
}
#container #siteBody .row .quad
{
 width:685px;
}
#container #siteBody .row .white
{
 background-color:white;
}
#container #siteBody .row .black-1
{
 background-color:black;
}
#container #siteBody .row .black-2
{
 background-color:#3b3e45;
}
#container #siteBody .row .green-1
{
 background-color:#00b159;
}
#container #siteBody .row .green-2
{
 background-color:#86aa26;
}
#container #siteBody .row .green-3
{
 background-color:#006054;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-1
{
 background-color:#00aedb;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-2
{
 background-color:#314e6c;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-3
{
 background-color:#44a5ac;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-4
{
 background-color:#297e83;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-5
{
 background-color:#034a8c;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-6
{
 background-color:#44a5ac;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-7
{
 background-color:#336797;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-8
{
 background-color:#0c5fa1;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-9
{
 background-color:#305b6e;
}
#container #siteBody .row .blue-10
{
 background-color:#00aaf0;
}
#container #siteBody .row .orange-1
{
 background-color:#f37735;
}
#container #siteBody .row .orange-2
{
 background-color:#b84e00;
}
#container #siteBody .row .orange-3
{
 background-color:#be4f3b;
}
#container #siteBody .row .pink-1
{
 background-color:#ec098c;
}
#container #siteBody .row .pink-2
{
 background-color:#f63150;
}
#container #siteBody .row .purple-1
{
 background-color:#7c4199;
}
#container #siteBody .row .purple-2
{
 background-color:#1d092c;
}
#container #siteBody .row .purple-3
{
 background-color:#640f6c;
}
#container #siteBody .row .red-1
{
 background-color:#d44032;
}
#container #siteBody .row .red-2
{
 background-color:#c9312c;
}
#container #siteBody .row .red-3
{
 background-color:#d11141;
}
#container #siteBody .row .red-4
{
 background-color:#ce0a0b;
}
#container #siteBody .row .yellow-1
{
 background-color:#ffc425;
}
#container #siteBody .row .yellow-2
{
 background-color:#e59b18;
}
#container #siteBody .row .yellow-3
{
 background-color:#e59a1a;
}
#container #siteBody .row .pointer
{
 cursor:pointer;
}
#container #siteBody .row .space
{
 margin-right:15px;
}
```

```html
<!doctype html>
<html dir="rtl">
 <head>
  <meta charset="windows-1255" />
  <title>
   Gate 7 || שער 7
  </title>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./style/main.css" />
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="container">
   <div id="siteBody">
    <div class="row">
     <div class="block single">
      <img src="./images/logo.png" />
     </div>
     <div class="block double" style="text-align:right;">
      שער 7
     </div>
     <div class="block single space">
      ימים
     </div>
     <div class="block single space">
      שעות
     </div>
     <div class="block single space">
      דקות
     </div>
     <div class="block single space">
      שניות
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="block triple blue-1"><span>
      דגשדגשדג
     </span></div>
     <div class="block single green-1 space">
      10
     </div>
     <div class="block single blue-2 space">
      50
     </div>
     <div class="block single pink-2 space">
      2
     </div>
     <div class="block single yellow-1 space">
      158
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
     <div class="block single purple-1">
      
     </div>
     <div class="block single blue-2 space">
      
     </div>
     <div class="block single orange-1 space">
      
     </div>
     <div class="block single yellow-1 space">
      
     </div>
     <div class="block single blue-7 space">
      
     </div>
     <div class="block single green-1 space">
      
     </div>
     <div class="block single blue-3 space">
      
     </div>
     <div class="clear"></div>
    </div>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```

Bottom line: the text isn't vertically aligned to the middle of the div.

I tried possibly any kind of solution suggested here, and couldn't find why it doesn't work.

Please help me!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**UPDATED**
Please add this lines in your css

```
#container #siteBody .row .block
{
   display:table; 
}

#container #siteBody .row .block span {
  display: table-cell;
  position: relative;
  vertical-align: middle;
}
```

this is the working solution even if your text in div will be increase, it will work..sorry for last quick answer..ty

Comment: Sorry but i forgot to tell you to remove top:50% but still m searching for better solution and soon will update my answer..this answer is just quick answer..hope i will find better one..

Comment: If he's fine with tables, that's a good solution. You can vertically align tables easy. I personally don't like them because they can be pain to work with in responsive.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this:

```
#container #siteBody .row .block {
  height: 160px;
  text-align: center;
  font-size: 25pt;
  font-weight: bold;
  float: right;
  line-height: 160px;
}
```

I've removed the `top:50%; transform:translateY(-50%);` trick as well from `#container #siteBody .row .block span`.

Basically you set the line height the same height as your container.

Comment: The problem with this solution is that I can have only one line of text using this... but I have multiple lines.

Comment: tried it... only one line is shown inside the div, the other ones are shown outside of it...

Answer (score 0):

See you have the following CSS code -

```
#container #siteBody .row .block
{
    height:160px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;
}
#container #siteBody .row .block span
{
    position:relative;
    top:50%;
    transform:translateY(-50%);
}
```

You just need a little changes to your original code -

```
#container #siteBody .row .block
{
    height:160px;
    text-align:center;
    font-size:25pt;
    font-weight:bold;
    float:right;
    position: relative; /* ADDED THIS LINE  */
}
#container #siteBody .row .block span
{
    position:absolute;  /* CHANGED THIS VALUE  */
    top:50%;
    left: 50%;          /* ADDED THIS LINE  */
    transform:translate(-50%, -50%);  /*CHANGED THIS VALUE  */
}
```